# R - slow performance in creating lots of data.table objects

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I am of course aware that the main purpose of `data.table` object is to allow fast subsetting/grouping etc., and it makes much more sense to have one big `data.table` and subset it (very efficiently) than having a lot of (possibly small) `data.table` objects.

That being said, I recently created a script that instantiates a lot of `data.table` objects and I noticed that the performances decrease as the number of in-memory `data.table's` grows.

Here's an example of what I mean :

```
n <- 10000
# create a list containing 10k data.frame's
system.time(lotsofDFs <- lapply(1:n,FUN=function(i){ data.frame(A=1:10,B=1:10,ID=i)}),gcFirst=T)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.24    0.00    2.23 
# create a list containing 10k data.table's
system.time(lotsofDTs <- lapply(1:n,FUN=function(i){ data.table(A=1:10,B=1:10,ID=i)}),gcFirst=T)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   5.49    0.01    5.53 
n <- 80000
# create a list containing 80k data.frame's
system.time(lotsofDFs <- lapply(1:n,FUN=function(i){ data.frame(A=1:10,B=1:10,ID=i)}),gcFirst=T)
#   user   system elapsed
#   19.42    0.01   19.53
# create a list containing 80k data.table's
system.time(lotsofDTs <- lapply(1:n,FUN=function(i){ data.table(A=1:10,B=1:10,ID=i)}),gcFirst=T)
#   user    system elapsed
#   147.03    0.10  147.41
```

As you can notice, while `data.frame's` creation time grows linearly with the number of `data.frame's` created, `data.table` complexity seems more than linear.

Is this expected?

Has this something to do with the list of in-memory tables (the one that you can see by calling `tables()` function) ?

---

**Environment :**

R version 3.1.2 (on Windows)
data.table 1.9.4

---

**EDIT :**

As pointed out by @Arun in the comments, `as.data.table(...)` seems to behave similarly to `data.frame(...)`. In fact, paradoxically `as.data.table(data.frame(...))` is faster than `data.table(...)` and time grows linearly with the number of objects, e.g. :

```
n <- 10000
# create a list containing 10k data.table's using as.data.table
system.time(lotsofDTs <- lapply(1:n,FUN=function(i){ as.data.table(data.frame(A=1:10,B=1:10,ID=i))}),gcFirst=T)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   5.04    0.01    5.04 
n <- 80000
# create a list containing 80k data.table's using as.data.table
system.time(lotsofDFs <- lapply(1:n,FUN=function(i){ as.data.table(data.frame(A=1:10,B=1:10,ID=i))}),gcFirst=T)
#   user   system elapsed
#   44.94    0.12   45.28
```

Comment: This must be pretty system dependent. I get 2.35 and 2.82 for df and dt respectively on the first two.

Comment: Did you run `Rprof()`? It should show you the time spent in `alloc.col` (over-allocation of column pointers)... :curious: what do you do with those 50K data.tables? I mean, what kind of task requires that many objects?

Comment: `as.data.table(list(...))` performs similar to `data.frame() / as.data.frame()`. Leads me to think that `data.table()` could be improved..

Comment: Sorry I was keeping the object in memory between the tests. Also the test was run in R-studio. Now I've re-run everything (separately) through Rscript.exe and updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Arun: I've tried Rprof but the bottleneck doesn't seem `alloc.col `. About the second question, well ... it was a small, quick'n'dirty script that has grown too much :(... basically I do a lot of simulations (100K) and each simulation produces a small data.table that I put into a list, and at the end I call rbindlist on that. Investigating about the slow performance I discovered this problem...so, actually I don't need 100K data.table, in fact at the moment I'm refactoring the script to have just one big data.table, but I wanted to report the issue I (painfully) found :)

Comment: @digEmAll, most of the time is spent on `.Call` - which is called from within `alloc.col`. So, I'm quite certain, it contributes quite a bit (on 10K+ tables). For your scenario, I'd suggest storing them as `list()` objects (as they're primitives), especially if you don't do any data.table-ish operation on them.. and then `rbindlist()` them..  - it also accepts lists-of-lists.

Comment: But thanks for the nice report, will take a look at why `data.table()` is slower, especially compared to `as.data.table()`. There are plans to move `data.table()` slowly to C, but no immediate plans...

Comment: @Arun: as I said I'm refactoring the code, so I don't think I will need this lots of data.table anymore... anyway thanks for the hint (and for your work on data.table package of course) :)

Comment: @digEmAll Out of curiosity, what is the size of the caches for your CPU? How much RAM does your machine have? Are you running 32 or 64 bit R? If you are instantiating large numbers of objects you could see high variance in performance based on what machine is running this code.

Comment: @MatthewCrews: now I have a new computer so I don't know the CPU cache but I had 8GB of RAM though. Anyway, I really think the problem was software related since other people had the same issue and also `as.data.table` behaved correctly. However, I haven't checked, but I guess this has been solved in the new data.table versions

Comment: Still the same issue with `data.table` version 1.10.4

Comment: May I suggest an alternate method, using setDT. In my machine, the performance is very close to the one for data.frame 35 sec(data.frame) vs 38 sec(setDT) vs 506sec(data.table). I am using data.table 1.10.4 (on Linux):

system.time(lotsofDFs <- lapply(1:n,FUN=function(i){ a<-data.frame(A=1:10,B=1:10,ID=i); setDT(a); a}),gcFirst=T)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setDT` :

```
n <- 80000
system.time(lotsofDTs <- lapply(1:n,FUN=function(i){setDT(list(A=1:10,B=1:10,ID=matrix(i,10)))}),gcFirst=T)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   6.75    0.28    7.17

system.time(lotsofDFs <- lapply(1:n,FUN=function(i){ data.frame(A=1:10,B=1:10,ID=i)}),gcFirst=T)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  32.58    1.40   34.22
```